# Passing the locale value in URL

Tags: jsf, primefaces, localization

I have a requirement where I need to display the same page in different language when the user selects a language from the dropdown.
For this I am using a selectOneMenu with multiple languages. When the user selects a language(locale) , the value should be appended to the url.

I have used the below code but it replaces the already present parameters from the url with locale.
Is there any way I can append the locale parameter without disturbing the parameters already present.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String contxRoot = ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
String viewId = ctx.getViewRoot().getViewId();
String URL=viewId+"?language="+this.selectedLaguage;

try {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(contxRoot+URL);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not a beauty, but you could try

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String contxRoot = ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
String initialUri = ((HttpServletRequest) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRequestURI();
String languageParameter = "?language="+this.selectedLaguage;

try {
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(contxRoot+initialUri+languageParameter);
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good candidate for storing in a @SessionScoped bean. Set the language in the bean and it can be used by all pages requested by the user (during the course of this session, of course).

A custom filter that intercepts a request and sets the language from the url and redirects appropriately can be option if, for example, a user wants to link to a URL in a particular language. Whether or not you actually want to allow that is up to you...